# How to load SpringBoot application.properties without PropertySource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm building a framework which can be used with/without Spring. So, I can't use the @PropertySource annotation.

How can I know exactly the application.properties path considering all possible variation. eg the user have changed the default path using --spring.config.location

Is there any Spring runtime variable which I can get this path?

Comment: Use environment variables instead of properties to set your configuration values.

Comment: You could also provide a own spring-boot-starter for your framework which then provides the configuration via spring-configuration-properties and also wraps your framework perfectly for usage in a springboot app

Answer (score 1):

just inject the Environment

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

it cointans a propertySourceList, which contains all property sources :)

maybe this is also interesting for you:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: oh, damn, you mean no spring at all? :D

Comment: If I understand my spring, the @Autowired will fail with no spring environment, and then you can grab params from the system properties.  I would wrap the class's property util and put the Environment var inside it, then optionally get other params when it's null.